# Different answers to $y'(x)=f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In different books I see different answers to the differential equation $y'(x)=f(x)$.

What is the difference between
$$
y(x)=\int f(x) \, dx + C
$$
and
$$
y(x)=\int f(x) \,dx =F(x) +C
$$
Are these equivalent? If so, why?

Thanks!

Comment: As long as you remember to add the arbitrary constant in somewhere, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: There's no difference, they're basically the same thing. In your first equation one antiderivative is taken, and to that a constant is added. In the second one all the antiderivative are considered as result of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

The two notations make the same point, but use subtly different interpretations of what the indefinite integral $\int f(x)\,dx$ means.

$$
y(x)=\int f(x) \, dx + C
$$
Here we imagine that $\int f(x)\,dx$ gives you one particular primitive function, chosen by your worst enemy among all primitives of $f(x)$. The formula then says that you can get every solution to the differential equation (and nothing but solutions) by adding a constant of *your* choosing.

$$
y(x)=\int f(x) \,dx =F(x) +C
$$
This formulation uses $\int f(x)\,dx$ as a meta-notation meaning the entire class of primitive functions of $f$ -- or in other words it encodes a whole family of equalities, one for each of those functions. The second equals sign then tells you what those primitives have in common. Now it is the notation $F(x)$ that stands for the primitive your enemy chose.

Answer (score 0):

Both the equations mean the same thing. It is fine if a constant is added anywhere. As long as there is a constant of integration to get a certain solution it is fine. Even if we take it as $$y(x) + C_1 = F(x) + C_2$$, it would mean the same thing as we can always create another constant $C = C_1 - C_2$ resulting in $$y(x) = F(x) + C$$

Answer (score 0):

Formally $\int f(x)dx$ is a **family** of functions $g$ such that $g'(x)=f(x)$, i.e. $\int f(x)dx$ is a family of all antiderivatives of $f$.

This notion $\int f(x)dx=F(x)+C$ is a shortcut for

$$\int f(x)dx=\{G_C\ |\ C\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

where $G_C(x)=F(x)+C$ for a given $F$.

On the other hand sometimes by $\int f(x)dx$ people mean any antiderivative (arbitrarly picked). In that case this notion $\int f(x)dx + C$ makes sense as well.

So all in all these are pretty much the same and are often used interchangeably. You just have to read from the context if it means a family of antiderivatives or any antiderivative.

Comment: Thanks! Before I have only seen this version $\int f(x) \, dx=F(x)+C$. Is it correct to interpret the second version as: $\int f(x) \, dx + C_1= F(x)+C_2+C_1=F(x)+C$? I just let $C=C_2+C_1$ Therefor the two expressions are equal?